# iOS: How to handle events from Bluetooth HFP devices?

Tags: ios, objective-c, bluetooth, avrcp, hfp

I'm trying to know how is possible to observe events from Bluetooth handsfree(Particular case - Plantronics M50) devices?
WatsApp does it, through the BTServer.
[image: Device console's logs:]

I've tried to catch event with:

1. MPRemoteCommandCenter

> ```
> MPRemoteCommandCenter* remoteCommandCenter = [MPRemoteCommandCenter sharedCommandCenter];
>     [[remoteCommandCenter togglePlayPauseCommand] addTarget:_sharedService action:@selector(didPressPlayPauseCommand)];
> ```

The approach works for headset, but not for Bluetooth handsfree.

2. UIApplication -beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents

> ```
> The same behaviour, as with MPRemoteCommandCenter. Doesn't work with bluetooth devices, but works with headset.
> ```

So, have anyone ideas, how to do the same job as it does WhatsApp?

Feel free to suggest anything on Swift. Any ideas? :)

Comment: It looks like you're trying to listen for phone call events.  Have you tried working with CallKit?  You could view any related events and update your app state accordingly.

Comment: @ChristopherLarsen Actually, I can't use CallKit due to, min version of my app is iOS 8. Any other ideas, how can I handle events?

Comment: Think you can use CTCallCenter from CoreTelephony for pre iOS10 https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coretelephony/ctcallcenter